# Spring boot jquery and bootstrap import

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, bootstrap-4

I have a basic spring boot project. I am trying to get http requet and response an html file using juery and bootstrap.

this is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is my conrtroller class.

```
@Controller
public class CountryController {
@Autowired
CountryRepository countryRepo;

@GetMapping("/")
public String showPage(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page) {
    model.addAttribute("data", countryRepo.findAll(new PageRequest(page, 4)));
    return "index";
}

@PostMapping
public String save(Country c) {
    countryRepo.save(c);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

In the html, I try to import jquery, bootstrap from webjars.
when I try to send get request over "/". spring boot says Request method 'GET' not supported. I have / controller with get mapping. i try to add webjar into classpath but failed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="webjars/jquery/3.3.1-1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Insert title here</title>
```

Comment: 404? what endpoint did you use?

Comment: i am calling / this one, in the html response, there is no jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: is your question that webjars aren't found? I have a similar project that uses webjars with similar structure as yours (the only difference is that I used `webjars-locators` so that I don't have to specify version), and it works fine. Can you provide full source (through github)?

Comment: i also added webjar locator but didnt work. a couple of maven update and install fixed the problem. now it is running. I have no idea why it wasnot running, before. anyway, ty for reply.

Comment: Ah you didn't do maven import...